# How to cancel function call from all go routines except one and use return value in all of them?

Tags: go, goroutine

I have this:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Manager struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    token string
}

func randString() string {
    return "32"
}

func (m *Manager) GenerateTokens() {
    m.Lock()
    m.token = randString() // just a random for example
    m.Unlock()

    fmt.Println("token created")
}

func NewManager() *Manager {
    m := &Manager{}
    m.GenerateTokens()
    return m
}

func (m *Manager) Work(countryCode string) {

    for  {
        err := m.Process()
        if err != nil {
            m.GenerateTokens()
            continue
        }
        break
    }

}

// Process just a function that may return an error
func (m *Manager) Process() error {
    randNum := rand.Intn(2)
    if randNum == 1 {
        return errors.New("error occurred")
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
    countryList := []string{"AE", "DE", "AU"}

    m := NewManager()
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, countryCode := range countryList {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(countryCode string) {
            m.Work(countryCode)
            wg.Done()
        }(countryCode)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

I tried to recreate my program in a more simple way.

There's a function called "GenerateTokens". This function generates some tokens that are used in all go routines. But there's a probability that these tokens may become expired, so we need to update them. And this error may occur in any go routine. So I need to call this function to recreate tokens in the go routine this error occurred, but others go routines must skip this function call because tokens are updated already and all they need to do is just to use new tokens that were updated on another go routine.

My question is how can I do this? Maybe I need to recreate my program in another way?

I tried to use context.WithCancel, but everything makes me pass the 'cancel' function into 'Work' function. I know that passing cancel around is unacceptable. But this is not the only problem. I also need to recreate this context because my loop is keep working. Even if I cancel this context, tokens must keep updating in next times, but If I have a closed context, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to simplify the acquisition of tokens. The `GenerateTokens` should always return a valid token.

```
func (m *Manager) GenerateTokens() string {
    m.Lock()
    defer m.Unlock()
    // todo check token expired
    if true {
        return m.token
    }
    fmt.Println("token created")
    m.token = randString() // just a random for example
    return m.token
}
```